# Retrieve the reference

Tags: perl, hash, arrays, reference

with the hash below, I would like the clients array's reference :

```
my $this = 
{
    'name' => $name, 
    'max_clients' => $max_clients, 
    'clients' => ()
};
```

I can't do "\$this{'clients'};" to retrieve the reference.

Comment: If you had enabled warnings, this would have given you an `odd number of elements in anonymous hash` warning as a clue that the `()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store an array as a value in a hash table. You can only store a scalar value such as a reference to an array:

```
my $this = 
{
    'name' => $name, 
    'max_clients' => $max_clients, 
    'clients' => [],
};
```

See also [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).